Ubuntu 22.04 / GeForce RTX2080 Ti $nvidia-smi No devices were found
На удаленном компе поменяли материнскую плату. Сейчас установлена "Gigabyte Technology
B760 GAMING X DDR4".
На новой плате есть встроенная видеокарта: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-S GT1 [UHD Graphics 770] (rev 04)
и стоящая в PCI слоте:
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU102 [GeForce RTX 2080 Ti Rev. A] (rev a1)
Устанавил компилятор gcc, необходимый для сборки CUDA
Установливал различные драйвера для Nvidia (520, 535, 550, 560)
Установил CUDA.
Однако, команда (sudo) nvidia-smi возвращает: No devices were found
Выполнил рекомендации документации Ubuntu: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/nvidia-drivers-installation, еще несколько вариантов с форума NVIDIA (https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvidia-smi-shows-no-devices-were-found-although-driver-is-installed/278118, https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=389943&utm_source=pocket_saves)
безрезультатно
сейчас cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version показывает, что:
NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX Open Kernel Module for x86_64 565.57.01 Release Build (dvs-builder@U16-A24-9-2) Thu Oct 10 12:15:00 UTC 2024 GCC version: gcc version 12.3.0 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)
выполнение $nvidia-settings возвращает ошибку: ERROR: nvidia-settings could not find the registry key file or the X server is not accessible. This file should have been installed along with this driver at /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation. The application profiles will continue to work, but values cannot be prepopulated or validated, and will not be listed in the help text. Please see the README for possible values and descriptions.
может быть кто-нибудь сталкивался с аналогичной проблемой и может поделиться опытом, как ее можно пофиксить.

судя по сообщению об ошибке or the X server is not accessible вам нужно стартовать на удалённой машине X сервер.

@PakUula nvidia-settings только для иксов и нужен, а ради только лишь CUDA не нужно трогать ни nvidia-settings, ни иксы

А выводы /proc/driver/nvidia/version и nvidia-smi мне кажутся противоречащими друг другу — модуль ядра в принципе откажется загружаться, если не найдёт видеокарту, а если он загрузился, значит видеокарта нашлась и nvidia-smi тоже должен что-нибудь толковое выводить

На форуме NVIDIA предлагают выполнить sudo nvidia-bug-report.sh и поискать что-нибудь подозрительное в свежесозданном файле nvidia-bug-report.log.gz (в частности что-нибудь со словом ERROR)

@andreymal  тем не менее, cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version и lspci показывает наличие Nvidia, а nvidia-smi - нет. Может быть, видеокарта Nvidia вышла из строя, но как -то так..., что показывает свое название, используемые ресурсы, но при этом не может выполнять функционал, который выполняется при nvidia-smi?
